# Can I set/change default index of an icon in an exe?

Tags: windows, mfc, icons, executable

My exe (an MFC application) contains several icons. I can see them and their indices through IconExplorer application. I noticed the indices of the icon changed when I build the same project under Windows 7 and XP (both were Visual Studio 2010 though). This is a problem because I refer to index of icons to register/set them during installation.

Is there a way I can control which icon can be set at index 0 and which can be at index 1 and so forth?

I have no idea why the indices changed from Windows 7 build and XP build which are both from the same copy of source code. If we can't assign the indices, wouldn't that make them somewhat redundant since we can't reliably use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the icon with the lowest ID value is placed first in your RC-file. This ensures the icon indeces remain consistent on all systems. Hence, sort them by their ID.

Also, make sure the ID values are greater than 128, since that's usually the value of the main icon (which you want to be at index 0).

UPDATE: Not sure about this, but perhaps the locale can interfere? E.g. Is any of your icons a non-neutral resource?

Comment: not sure about what non-neutral means but like any other applications my exe has few .ico files. I thought it has to do with resource ids like u pointed but they are essentially identical in both builds.

Comment: You can open your exe in VisualStudio, and use the resource editor there to view the compiled resources directly.  To the best of my knowledge, the lowest ID is ALWAYS placed in the file first, followed by the next lowest ID, and so on...

Comment: I would assume the resource IDs are identical. However, they must be in ascending order. Otherwise the indeces might fail on *some* systems.

Comment: You are right, my bad. There was one file difference in both files which were resource ids. That fixed it.